# Adding tag scopes in universal-ctags

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm currently writing an external tags generator for universal-ctags to get better groovy support. Given that groovy already has AST support, I'm just implementing via a simple groovy script (see [here](https://github.com/bangroot/ctags-castle/blob/master/home/.ctags.d/drivers/groovytags) if you care).

My problem is that even though I output `class:<ClassName>` in the extra fields, universal-ctags drops it from the output ... I presume there is something telling it what languages support which tag scopes.

For instance, when I run with the same flags that TagBar uses ...

```
ctags -f - --format=2 --excmd=pattern --extra= --fields=nksaSmt
```

... for Java source I'll get output akin to:

```
ThisClass       src/main/java/ThisClass.java  /^      public ThisClass(String name) {}$/;"    m       line:24 class:ThisClass access:public   signature:(String name)
```

However, when run against a file using my xcmd through ctags, the output is:

```
start   src/main/groovy/Main.groovy    /^      def start(String m) {$/;"      m       line:34 access:public   signature:(String m)
```

Even though the output directly from my xcmd shows the proper output:

```
start   src/main/groovy/Main.groovy       /^      def start(String m) {$/;"      m       class:Main      access:public      signature:(String m)   line:34
```

Is there some way to get universal-ctags to echo out my tag scopes?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but: a tag file is just a collection of those lines with a small header, so the easier solution might just be to dump the output of your xcmd to a file?

Comment: Good point ... I was just hoping it would fit into my workflow a bit better for mixed source projects.

Comment: Ask this as an issue in Universal Ctags github page. Masatake will surely reply to you as soon as possible.